# If I want to talk about a country as an animated thing, should I use a she, he or it?

Tags: pronouns

If I want to talk about a country as an animated thing (i.e., creating a meme that represents an action, where one subject is a country), should I use a "she", "he" or "it"?

Comment: Up to you.  There are no rules; whatever makes your meme work best.  In normal conversation, inanimate objects are usually referred to as "it", but if you want to anthropomorphize something, a gendered pronoun would emphasize that more.  Historically, personified abstractions were typically female, but that convention is all but dead today, outside somewhat-affected or at least flowery political speeches. So you should decide whether your country is a man, woman, or neuter, and write accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't use "¿".

Comment: Here  in the US we have "Uncle Sam" personifying the country.  Probably use "he" in that case.

Comment: However, God Bless America: "Stand beside her, and guide her through the night with a light from above."